# Spotlight hangs on ical item

Tags: spotlight

My iMac (early 2009) is super slow and spotlight and timemachine doesnt work at all. I am suspecting the the spotlight index (which never seem to finish) is behind some of the performance issues. I have reset the spotlight index and deleted the old files and restarted indexing. I am snooping the progress with this command: `sudo opensnoop -n mdworker` and then I can see that the indexing seems to halt on `0    169 mdworker       5 /.vol/16777218/695996`

I suspect that this is a calendar event? How can I see if spotlight indexing is crashing and restarting? I have let it run for hours and it never finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like it's just stalling on a corrupt file.

Try typing

```
GetFileInfo /.vol/16777218/695996
```

into the Terminal to find out what the file is.

If you're right about Spotlight stalling on a calendar event, try going into preferences and disabling the indexing of Events and Reminders. And then resetting spotlight.

Comment: I gave up and did a clean install of mavericks. Everything is now peachy.